# How can I get position of a div realtive to window without using scrollTop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ipad, scroll

Is it possible with JavaScript to get the position of a div relative to window without using `scrollTop()`?

I have seen examples of doing this by getting the absolute with `offset()` and comparing that to `scrollTop()`.

But, I want to do this during scrolling on iPad, where scrollTop is first set after scroll completed. So, can I somehow get the position in an other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `iPad` use `window.pageYOffset` to get `scrollTop` and use your normal logic it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

position().top is a good one to use, but as for getting the live position as scroll is happening, not totally sure that's possible because of how safari is firing events... it doesn't work quite like a regular browser in that sense.

You can listen for a window scroll event and see if it logs live position, but I don't believe it will :/